# Error while selecting input field with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, xpath, instagram

in the following code I was trying to perform a login to an Instagram account using Selenium with python.

I have used different methods to locate the field and to fill them with proper data but in all cases, it couldn't locate the element.

These are the fields that I was trying to fill: `Username`

```
<input aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value="">
```

Password:

```
<input aria-label="Password" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="password" type="password" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value="">
```

here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class InstagramBot():
    def __init__(self,username, password):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        time.sleep(4)

    def login(self):
        self.browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')

        usernameInput = self.browser.find_element_by_name('username')
        passwordInput = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password')
        usernameInput.send_keys(self.username)
        passwordInput.send_keys(self.password)
        self.browser.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(2)


bot = InstagramBot('MY_USERNAME', 'MY_PASSWORD')
bot.login()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There is nothing wrong with your script, just wait for the page to load using [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)*

*Or move `time.sleep(4)` after `self.browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')`*

```
def login(self):
    self.browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')
    time.sleep(4)
    usernameInput = self.browser.find_element_by_name('username')
    passwordInput = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password')
    usernameInput.send_keys(self.username)
    passwordInput.send_keys(self.password)
```

Answer (score 1):

Propably you search for element before your page even load as you imediatelly search for elements after browser get method , best way is not sleep but Wait

try:

```
from selenium import webdriver                                                  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys                                 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By                                     
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait                         
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC                
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import sys

### your browser definition etc
wait  = WebDriverWait(browser, 4)
# now your browser will wait for 4 seconds and will throw an error if he didnt finds the element
try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="STRUCTURED_EDITOR.FLIGHT_DATA_AREA.GENERAL_DATA_ENTRY.AIRCRAFT_ID_FIELD"]')))
except TimeoutException:
    print("time error")
    self.browser.quit()

element_drop_down = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="STRUCTURED_EDITOR.FLIGHT_DATA_AREA.GENERAL_DATA_ENTRY.AIRCRAFT_ID_FIELD"]')
element_drop_down.send_keys("{}".format(my_var))
```

Also check if there are multiple frames cause you need to switch frame if the elemnt is inside a secondary frame

Comment: Hey dude, thanks for your response. Can you please tell me where should I put the code you have mentioned?

Comment: Oh sorry  just put it after your browser.get the page you wanna find the elements.check the typos cause i gave a general example